# Inconsistence results when executing Rscript with php

Tags: php, linux, r, apache, rscript

When running a R function I created with Rscript command in ubuntu terminal (after *su* to Apache server www-data user) I get perfect results (function code not inserted due to length).
However, when running the same function via php `exec("Rscript wrapper.R $N)"` on Apache I get absolutely nothing.

Note that other R functions I tried (like `rnorm`) work just fine.

Is there some difference between the terminal run (again, in www-data user so permissions should not be a problem) and the php `exec` that I am not aware of? What could be the source of such differences in results?

Comment: Just a guess, but I would first check how/what you are returning.  Can you post the last few lines of your `R` function

Comment: Try inserting something like `write(x=3, file="test.txt")` right before the end of your `R` function and see if the `test.txt` file is created.  If so, then you know the function is executing and you simply need to check how you are returning the expected output